# Fill the QRect on enter event

Tags: c++, qt

I have a task: QRect object should be painted when mouse cursor entering it.
After a couple of hours I made this.

```
void myObj::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event){   
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    QPoint point = event->pos();
    rect->getCoords(&x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
    if((point.x() >= x1) && (point.x() <= x2) && (point.y() >= y1) && (point.y() <= y2)){
       changeRectColour();
    }else{
       brush->setColor(Qt::green);
       repaint();
    }
}
```

myObj is inherited from QWidget.
But I think that my idea isn't efficient. Because on every mouse move outside the QRect it changes color to green(even if it's green).
Unfortunatelly, QRect hasn't enterEvent() function.
Can you, please, give an advice how to do this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QWidget::repaint()` means **"paint now!!! I can't wait!"**. Use [QWidget::update()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update) instead, which will fold several paint requests into one (better explanation in the doc).

Btw you are basically reimplementing `QRect::contains()`. Your new code will be

```
void myObj::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event){   

    QPoint point = event->pos();
    if(rect->contains(point, true)){
       changeRectColour(); 
    }
    else{
       brush->setColor(Qt::green);
       update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean class member e.g. `_lastPositionWasInsideRect`, initialize that to `false` and program your if statement somewhat like this:

```
bool positionIsInsideRect = (point.x() >= x1) && (point.x() <= x2) && (point.y() >= y1) && (point.y() <= y2));

if( positionIsInsideRect && !_lastPositionWasInsideRect )
{
    _lastPositionWasInsideRect = true;
    // do the changes which are required when entering the rect
}
else if( !positionIsInsideRect && _lastPositionWasInsideRect )
{
    _lastPositionWasInsideRect = false;
    // do the changes which are required when leaving the rect     
}
```

A much easier alternative would be to consider using the [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html) framework.